# Unable to overwrite appSettings in WebApplicationFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to set integration tests for my .Net 6 Api using `WebApplicationFactory` but no matter what I do it continues to use the values from `appsettings.Development.json`

I've tried many different solutions but during my test it always using the dev connection string.

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        ...
        var app = builder.Build();
        ...
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

AppFactory.cs

```
public class AppFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((config, builder) => 
        {
            var appSettings = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ConnectionStrings::DefaultConnection", "server=test"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ApiUrl", "https://somethingelse.com")
            };

            builder.Sources.Clear();
            builder.AddInMemoryCollection(appSettings);
        });
    }
}
```

ApiTests.cs

```
[TestClass]
public class ApiTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        var application = new AppFactory();
        using var client = application.CreateClient();

        var content = JsonContent.Create(new LoginRequest
        {
            Username = "myusername@test.com",
            Password = "mypassword123"
        });

        var response = await client.PostAsync("/login", content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still seeing dev connection string being used because at the time when you are overwriting database connection, your database configuration has already been created using dev connection string and registered within DI. Place breakpoints inside initial database configuration code and inside web app factory where you are overwriting connection string. See which gets hit first.

You'll have to overwrite the database configuration in dedicated for that method `ConfigureTestServices()`. I usually replace the dev configuration with test configuration. In the example below, I'm replacing SQL-Server provider for EF with In-Memory provider:

```cs
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
        // Remove already registered DbContext options.
        RemoveDbContextOptions<AppDbContext>(services);

        // Create seperate service provider.
        var internalServiceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        // Add a database context using an in-memory database for testing.
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemory");
            options.UseInternalServiceProvider(internalServiceProvider);
        });
    });
}

private void RemoveDbContextOptions<TDbContext>(IServiceCollection services)
    where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    var descriptor = services.Single(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<TDbContext>));

    services.Remove(descriptor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to overwrite appSettings in WebApplicationFactory

You can try to modify the AppFactory as below:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            config.Sources.Clear();
            // Add your custom configuration here
            var customSettings = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection", "server=test"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ApiUrl", "https://somethingelse.com")
            };
            var newConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder() 
                .AddInMemoryCollection(customSettings)
                .Build();
            config.AddConfiguration(newConfig);
        }); 
        // Do not call base.ConfigureWebHost(builder) here.
        // The base implementation will be called automatically.
    }
}
```

Then in the APITest class: as we can see, we need to install the Xunit package.

```
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using Xunit;
using Assert = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert;

namespace UnitTestAPI.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class APITests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>>
    {
        private HttpClient _httpClient;

        public APITests()
        {
            var webAppFactory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>();
            _httpClient = webAppFactory.CreateClient();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task Test()
        {  
            var content = JsonContent.Create(new LoginRequest
            {
                UserName = "myusername@test.com",
                Password = "mypassword123"
            });

            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("/login", content);
            var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

           Assert.IsNotNull(stringResult);
        }
```

The API controller code as below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    public ValuesController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _config = configuration;
    }

    // POST api/<ValuesController>
    [HttpPost("/login")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] LoginRequest login)
    {
        var connection = _config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection").Value;
        var url = _config.GetSection("ApiUrl").Value;
        return Ok(login);
    }
```

Before overriding, we can get the development setting:

[image]

After overriding the app setting, the output as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Debugging my test it's still connecting to my dev db and I can see all the rows for that table in the debugger. Does this only work with XUnit or can it also work with MSTest?

Comment: @user3953989 , my test project is a MSTest Test project, and in this project, I installed the xunit page, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OdgS.png).